# Type mismatch in dao insert - how to convert list of object to entity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dao

In my Kotlin application I'm using Retrofit to retrieve data from network and room to store these data locally.

In the `ViewmMdel` I want to get the `asteroid` objects and store them in local database.
The main problem is the network call returns `ArrayList` of data class called Asteroid
And the `Dao` expects an `ArrayList` of `Asteroid` Entity.

So basically I have 2 asteroids classes. One represents an entity for room and the other as model for network call.

I have this funcion in `ViewModel`

```
private fun getAsteroids() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            var result = repository.getAsteroid()
            _asteroidList.value = result.toMutableList()
            appLocalDb.asteroidDao.insertFeed(result)
           
        } catch (e : Exception) {
            _asteroidList.value = null
        }
    }
```

}

Here `getAsteroids` in repository

```
   override suspend fun getAsteroid(): ArrayList<Asteroid> {
        return apiRepositoryImp.getAsteroids();
    }
```

`insertFeed` in Dao

```
@Dao
interface AsteroidDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertFeed(vararg asteroid: Asteroid)
}
```

Here's the error

```
Required:
com.asteroidradar.repository.db.entity.Asteroid
Found:
kotlin.collections.ArrayList<com.asteroidradar.Asteroid> /* = java.util.ArrayList<com.asteroidradar.Asteroid> */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must convert `com.asteroidradar.repository.db.entity.Asteroid` `com.asteroidradar.Asteroid` by following code:

```
 var result = repository.getAsteroid()
 _asteroidList.value = result.toMutableList()
 appLocalDb.asteroidDao.insertFeed(*result.map{ repoAsteroid ->
    com.asteroidradar.Asteroid(
      //Set full properties here
    )
 }.toTypedArray())
```

See the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

Comment: I have tried this before and it's showing another error 
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: 
required:
Array<out com.asteroidradar.repository.db.entity.Asteroid>
found:
Array<com.asteroidradar.Asteroid>

Comment: Please check com.asteroidradar.repository.db.entity.Asteroid and com.asteroidradar.Asteroid. The app contains 2 Asteroid models, the one in com.asteroidradar.repository.db.entity package and another Asteroid in com.asteroidradar package

Comment: Yes and this is what I wrote in the question. I'm having 2 models as entity and another one for API calls I don't want to mix both. is it not applicable?

Comment: Yes, you must convert com.asteroidradar.Asteroid to com.asteroidradar.repository.db.entity.Asteroid by creating new instance

Comment: I have just updated my answer. Please check it